# Issue with outcome of task process defaulting to Approved

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I am currently struggling with a designer workflow and hope to see if someone here has a solution.

The environment is Office 365 SP 2013, so no option to use anything but SPD workflows.

I have a simple workflow that is triggered manually by the user to start a custom sp 2013 workflow which in the first stage starts a Task Process with multiple users in parallel.

My issue is that I want the Workflow to react to a single rejection to terminate the task process and set the task outcome to rejected. Unfortunately SP 2013 disagrees with me on this and seems to be going on some sort of genius assumption that 1 person approving and 1 person rejecting = task outcome Approved.

In 2010 Approval Workflows there was the option to cancel on first rejection, but I cannot find the equivalent in the 2013 workflow settings.

Has anyone found a way to ensure that a 2013 task process running in parallel and not serially closes itself with Rejected status if someone rejects?

The Workflow Action is Called "Start a task process with "Users" (Task Outcome to Variable: Outcome"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, please read carefully the description:
"Wait for all" completion criteria will return outcome that received the most number of responses.

It is unclear what you actually want to achieve so please choose one following

1. If someone rejects the workflow stops and tasks in progress are cancelled. Set "Wait for first response", required outcome to "Reject", and default outcome to "Approved". Workflow will immediately stop if someone has rejected.
2. If you want to wait for all responses and then if at least one rejected reject the workflow otherwise to approve, you should specify "Wait for percentage", "100%", "Approved", Default Outcome "Rejected". Workflow will collect all the responses.

Comment: Thanks the Wait for first response options solved it for me eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the `Wait for task completion` option setting the `Completion criteria" to "Wait for first response` ?

Comment: If you are asking for clarification then please use the comment option instead of answer.